# Onedrive for Business - Cannot share file/folder: 403 "forbidden"

Tags: azure, onedrive, office365-apps

I setup one iOS app in Azure Portal to integrate with OneDrive for business.

In "Permission to other app" we selected all permission for 
- Microsoft Graph
- Office 365 sharepoint online
- Window Azure Active Directory

I run iOS sample code in SDK and it works for almost functions accept for "Share file". Error: 403 "forbidden" UserInfo={error=notAllowed: The feature has been disabled. Please contact your admin to get it enable., NSLocalizedDescription=forbidden}

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdPYn.png)

Maybe I missed any configuration somewhere? Could you please advice

Thanks Regards,

Hoang

Answer (score 0):

How did you share the file, create a share link or invite the people? Based on the test, the OneDrive REST API both works well for the creating the share link and invite people. Can you reproduce this issue using the OneDrive REST API?

Here is the OneDrive REST API for your reference.

Share link:

POST https://msdnofficedev-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/01EOIEB3KQBZ74CI7DYBELCRPNZVJKSOUC/action.createLink

Header:

```
authorization: bearer {token}

Content-Type: application/json
```

Body:

```
{
  "type": "view"
}
```

Invite people:

POST https://msdnofficedev-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/01EOIEB3KQBZ74CI7DYBELCRPNZVJKSOUC/action.invite

Header:

```
authorization: bearer {token}

Content-Type: application/json
```

Body:

```
{
  "requireSignIn": false,
  "sendInvitation": true,
  "roles": ["write"],
  "recipients": [
  { "email": "user1@msdnofficedev.onmicrosoft.com" }
  ],
  "message": "Here's the document I was talking about yesterday."
}
```

And you can refer to the link below to get the Access token:
https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm